# plot arrival and departure times that cross midnight

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, lubridate

I am trying to plot an animal's arrival to and departure from a given site. The animal arrives in the afternoon/evening and departs the following morning. Sometimes the animal arrives after midnight, thus both arrival and departure occur on the same date.

How can I scale the x axis so that the times are centered around midnight? In both examples in the reprex below, the problem is that the x axis is scaled from morning to night, thus showing the animal's departure time from the previous day before its arrival time that night, whereas what I would like is to show each day's arrival time and what time it departed the next day. How can I scale the x axis so each segment begins at the arrival time and ends at the departure time the following morning?

Thank you for any ideas!

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(hms)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'hms'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     hms
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(reprex)

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2021-04-19", "2021-04-20", "2021-04-21", "2021-04-22", "2021-04-23", "2021-04-24", "2021-04-26")),
  arrival_time = ymd_hms(c("2021-04-19 19:03:00", "2021-04-20 19:50:00", "2021-04-21 20:04:00", "2021-04-22 20:52:00", "2021-04-23 21:06:00",
                           "2021-04-24 21:22:00", "2021-04-26 01:47:00")),
  departure_time = ymd_hms(c("2021-04-20 06:00:00", "2021-04-21 05:47:00", "2021-04-22 06:23:00", "2021-04-23 05:56:00",
                            "2021-04-24 04:59:00", "2021-04-25 06:32:00", "2021-04-27 06:40:00"))
)

# attempt 1 - plot separate date variable on y axis
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as_hms(arrival_time), xend = as_hms(departure_time), y = date, yend = date)) +
  scale_y_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d %b") +
  labs(x = "Time at Site",
       y = "Date")
```

[image]

```r
# attempt 2 - plot actual date of POSIXct variable on y axis 
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as_hms(arrival_time), xend = as_hms(departure_time), y = date(arrival_time), yend = date(departure_time))) +
  scale_y_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d %b") +
  labs(x = "Time at Site",
       y = "Date")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution were I first calculate the difference and duration, which is also correct if the duration goes over 1 day (as in your last row).

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        # Extract hms to plot all on the same day, convert back to datetime otherwise we need to use scale_x_time, without date_breaks and date_labels option
        arrival = hms::as_hms(arrival_time) %>% lubridate::as_datetime(),
        # calculate difference between cols and with the result the duration
        diff = lubridate::interval(arrival_time, departure_time),
        dur = lubridate::as.duration(diff) # this is the duration they are on site
        # workaround if arrival is after midnight
        arrival = if_else(day(arrival_time) > day(date), arrival + days(1), arrival),
    ) %>%
    # show our intermediate result
    glimpse() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = arrival, y = date, group = date)) +
    # using point range as I think it looks nicer
    # important xmax is now arrival plus the duration
    geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = arrival, xmax = arrival + dur)) +
    # also add a text label why not
    geom_text(aes(label = dur, x = arrival + hours(2)), nudge_y = 0.3) +
    scale_y_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d %b") +
    scale_x_datetime(
        date_breaks = "1 hour",
        date_labels = "%H"
    ) +
    labs(
        x = "Time at Site",
        y = "Date"
    )
```

[image: example image]

PS: you don't need to load `hms` and `ggplot2` they both come with `tidyverse` autoloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could try subtracting 12 hours from the times then adding 12 hours to their labels.

First write a labelling function:

```r
# The hms format stores time as seconds internally.
# There are 86400 seconds in 24 hours and 43200 seconds in 12 hours, so our
# labelling function adds 43200 seconds to increase the time values by 12
# hours, then gives the result modulo 86400 to deal with values above 24 hours.
# The result is an integer number of seconds, so we need to convert this with as_hms.
# Finally we take the first 5 characters of the result with substr to give %H:%M
# formatted character strings as the labels

labelling_fn <- function(x) {
  (as.numeric(x + 43200) %% 86400) %>%
     as_hms()                      %>%
     substr(1, 5)
}
```

Now pass the labelling function to the `labels` argument of `scale_x_time`

```r
df %>%
ggplot(aes(y = date(arrival_time), xmin = as_hms(arrival_time - hours(12)),
           xmax = as_hms(departure_time - hours(12)))) +
  geom_linerange() +
  scale_x_time(labels = labelling_fn) +
  scale_y_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d %b") +
  labs(x = "Time at Site",
       y = "Date")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Allan - this is a much cleaner solution than everything else I have tried! How would you go about formatting x-axis labels to just show %H:%M? When I try to specify breaks or add a formatting call to the labels argument it overrides the labels function you wrote and leaves the x-axis blank with no labels.

Comment: @m.hand sure - you can format the label however you please. I have seperated out the labelling function from the ggplot call in my update to make this clearer.

Comment: Aha! Thank you.